# How to pass more than 1 string in Range.Find.execute in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I want to search a few characters like "%" or "&" or "@" in a Word Document with hundreds of lines. Word has **Range.Find.execute** method which is used to search the strings in Documents but I am unable to use it.

In

> Object findText ;

we pass the string which is to be found in the Document.

How can I pass more than 1 string into findText Object. *For eg.* It should search for either of these **"%"**, **"&"**, **"@"** , whichever comes first.

Please help me with a sample code, the implementation of the Find.execute method according to my requirement.

Thanks

```
            Object findText = "@"; // have to use "%" and "&" as well

            Object matchCase = Type.Missing;

            Object matchWholeWord = Type.Missing;

            Object matchWildCards = Type.Missing;

            Object matchSoundsLike = Type.Missing;

            Object nmatchAllWordForms = Type.Missing;

            Object forward = Type.Missing;

            Object wrap = Type.Missing; 

            Object format = Type.Missing;

            Object replaceWithText = Type.Missing;

            Object replace = Type.Missing; //object replace = WdReplace.wdReplaceNone; 

            Object matchKashida = Type.Missing;

            Object matchDiacritics = Type.Missing;

            Object matchAlefHamza = Type.Missing;

            Object matchControl = Type.Missing;

            Word.Range rng = this.Content; 
            rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
            if (rng.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase,
                ref matchWholeWord, ref matchWildCards,
                ref matchSoundsLike, ref nmatchAllWordForms,
                ref forward, ref wrap, ref format,
                ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics,
                ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl))
            {
                // Do Something
            }
```

Comment: `findText` is an `Object`, you can pass an array of strings. Have you tried it?

Comment: @vivek If I pass array of strings in findText and use it in Find.Execute, I have to pass the index of the array as well.. then what is use of array string..? Can you help me out with the Code here if I am missing anything..  
I have to perform some action everytime a character is found and have to search for another character on button press..

Comment: Have you tried ? "[@%&]"

Comment: I did it via Object array of Strings.. It worked fine